# How to style WordPress Menu Item with children pages differently?

Tags: wordpress, menu, submenu

I am trying to style my WP Menu Navbar. I want that the Pages that have children pages can be styled differently (mainly reducing the bottom margin, so that it is clear that the children pages belong to the parent page).

I know how to inspect a site and tried to target possibly every class that is listed there. But nothing is working. The site isn't live yet, but I will attach a screenshot of Google Inspect. It's the "menu-item-425" that I want to style differently.

I tried targeting like this:

```
.main-menu-links .menu-item .menu-item-has-children ul li a {
  color: black;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

But nothing changes. Any advice?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove space between .menu-item and .menu-item-has-children like this

```
.main-menu-links .menu-item.menu-item-has-children ul li a {
  color: black;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

I guess these are classes of the same element.